# Webscrape multiple tables with R (rvest)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, scrape

I'm trying to scrape all the tables on the wiki page for CSI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CSI:_Crime_Scene_Investigation_episodes
so far so good I've been able to scrape one table (season 1) with the code below,
is there a for loop that could just loop through all the tables since they have the same class?

here is my R code

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CSI:_Crime_Scene_Investigation_episodes"
episodes <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(14)') %>%
  html_table()
episodes <- episodes[[1]]
```

Update i just realised that each table selector has a different nth child selector, so i decided to assign each table selector to a variable like below. can i loop through each table now and assign the results to one DF/varible "episodes"
adjusted code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CSI:_Crime_Scene_Investigation_episodes"
table1<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(14)'
table2<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(18)'
table3<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(22)'
table4<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(26)'
table5<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(30)'
table6<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(34)'
table7<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(38)'
table8<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(42)'
table9<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(46)'
table10<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(50)'
table11<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(54)'
table12<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(58)'
table13<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(62)'
table14<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(66)'
table15<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(70)'
table16<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(74)'
#table17<- '#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(79)'
episodes <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(table1) %>%
  html_table(fill = T)
episodes <- episodes[[1]]

write.csv(population, file = "test.csv")
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want to scrape the table for each season?

Comment: Yes, I want the table for each season if possible in a data frame. so far I can scrape one table at a time.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it correctly, what you are trying to do is to put in a single data frame all tables except the first one, which lists the seasons and has different column names.

Assuming you have installed `purrr` and `dplyr` (both part of the `tidyverse`), the following should achieve what you want: first extract all tables, then put all of them (bar the first) in a single data frame.

```r
library(rvest)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CSI:_Crime_Scene_Investigation_episodes"

episodes <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

purrr::map_dfr(episodes[-1], dplyr::bind_rows)
```

To clarify, the first pipe of commands creates a list of data frames with all tables.

`map_dfr` tells it to iterate over the given list and output a data frame.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but so far I've tried it but didn't work. Returned a bunch of NA's.